# Environment variable not picked up by Tomcat server when started from java main program

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to call startup.sh file from my main application but Environment variables from catalina.sh files are not picked up . Are Environment variables from parent thread are passed to child thread or what's causing this ? . Its works perfectly when i start it independently from console . I am using Runtime.exec to run the ./startup.sh command from my main application .Please help tp understand this .

Comment: Sharing your `Runtime.exec` content and (fragments of) `catalina.sh` would probably help. What operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 : try {
   Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: String command="C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.27-windows-x86\\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\\bin\\startup.bat";
  try {
   Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   System.out.println("Process Id "+child.toString());
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: In your question you use startup.sh and in your comment you specify startup.bat. Which is it? Also, it would be better if you edited the question to add the additional info.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```java
String[] cmdarray = { "cmd", "/c", "call", "startup.bat" };
File tomcatDir = new File("C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.27-windows-x86\\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\\bin");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray, null, tomcatDir);
```

See if it helps.

Off the thread, it's better to provide additional information by editing the question, not by adding comments - esp. if you need to paste code or logs.